# Flutter http_proxy not working for iOS device

Tags: flutter, http, proxy

The Flutter app for iOS devices doesn't accept the system proxy instead uses a different IP address for the Network API calls.

This is the solution I followed to make flutter proxy aware.

```
import 'package:http_proxy/http_proxy.dart';

HttpProxy httpProxy = await HttpProxy.createHttpProxy();
HttpOverrides.global = httpProxy;
```

This works for Android but doesn't work on iOS. Is there any solution to make the flutter app proxy aware on iOS too?